# Why suddenly MagentoGo is shutting down?

Tags: discussion

Sad to see that Magento Go will shut down on 2015. (see http://go.magento.com/) At the same time Bigcommerce supports integrate MagentoGo migraitions.
 Any reasons for this? And what's the status of Magento community and Enterprise?

Comment: Being a question about magento and not about magento.SE, I think this is a valid question for [main](http://magento.stackexchange.com/) instead of meta. It would even have more visibility.

Comment: +1 I would also like to know.

Comment: You can ask yourself: "Why does a business shut down?"